# Does the "she was found in violation of..." <-> "she was violated" equivalence have a name?

Tags: verbs, phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis, semantic-shift

This is a follow-up to this question: [Why is "violated" being used as future perfect with a person as the object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322055/why-is-violated-being-as-future-perfect-with-a-person-as-the-object)

At that question, it was established that there is a jargon/slang usage of the word "violated" within the aviation community that means "found to be in violation of". As in "The pilot will be violated..." means "The pilot will be found in violation of a regulation" in that context.

Does this type of thing have a name?

Are you aware of any other verbs that have been inverted like this? For example, something like this completely made up example: "*She was found to be in possession of drugs*" meaning the same thing as, "*She was possessed*", even if only in a slang/non-standard/jargon context?

Comment: This Wikipedia article seems related: [Unaccusativity in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb#Unaccusativity_in_English)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name for a verb that switches meaning depending on whether it has an object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230563/name-for-a-verb-that-switches-meaning-depending-on-whether-it-has-an-object)

Comment: @sumelic I think that's different. It's not like "Emily closes the door" means the same as "Emily will be closed". In this context, it's that "Emily will be found in violation of the regulation" means the same as "Emily will be violated"

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diathesis_alternation.

Comment: It should be noted that exchanging subject and object is a common error made by E2L speakers, and is also sometimes seen in "illiterate" E1L speech.  It's a variation on the "teach"<==>"learn" swap that is seen in some rural dialects in the US.

Comment: suggest add "jargon" tag --

Answer (score 5):

It’s an example of ***zero derivation***. This means deriving a new word from another word while bypassing the usual derivation rule that involves adding a prefix or suffix such as *‑ify* or *‑ize*. To illustrate zero derivation, here is an example from the [exploding penguin sketch](http://www.ibras.dk/montypython/episode22.htm):

> (1) Oh, *intercourse* the penguin. [*Emphasis added*]

Monty Python derive ?*intercourse* (trans) from *intercourse* (subj), creating a funny euphemism for *fuck* (trans). This is a zero derivation because it takes place without a verb-creating suffix. (Zero-deriving a verb from a noun is also known as “[verbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation))” the noun.)

Your example is a zero derivation of a new word, not just a figurative use of an existing word. This can be seen from the fact that the new word has different restrictions on how it can be used. The existing word,

> (2) **violate** (trans), *to treat with violence or dishonor*

takes as its object the target of the violence or dishonor. It can be a person, but it can also be a law, regulation, or custom.

The new word,

> (3) **violate** (trans), *to sanction* (a person, for a rule violation)

takes as its object the person being sanctioned.

So:

> (4) Harry violated *Sally*.
>
> (5) Harry violated *Texas law*.
>
> (6) The investigator will violate *Harry* for police misconduct.

But not:

> (7) *The investigator will violate *Texas law* for Harry’s misconduct.

The difference is apparent in the ambiguity of (4) and the absence of ambiguity of (5). *Violated* in statement (4) could be either *violate* (2) or *violate* (3). It may mean Harry sanctioned Sally for a rule violation, or that Harry committed a violent act upon Sally. But *violated* in statement (5) unambiguously means *violate* (2), Harry dishonored the law. This is because only *violate* (2) can take a law, regulation, or custom as its object.

Another example of zero derived professional slang is

> (8) **KA** (trans), to identify a person’s “known associates”, from *KA* (subj), a person’s “[known associates](https://www.reddit.com/r/TrueDetective/comments/1wp6p9/detective_jargon_and_slang_thread/)”.

Example:

> (9) I’ll *KA* the victim.

Besides the references linked above, the article “[Verbing Nouns](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/verbing.html)” by John Lawler was very helpful in writing this answer.

<sup><sub>The [lawler weight](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/measuring-typographical-emphasis-the-lawler-and-lawler-weight) of this answer is `0.55 lw`.</sub></sup>

Comment: Using a different sense of *lawler weight*, meaning both *fascinating* and *demonstrating impeccable grammatical chops* simultaneously, I propose the lawlerweight of this post is 7. If I could, upvote you again for the link to that meta-post, which I'd never seen before.

Comment: @DanBron Possibly because it was closed.

Comment: Arguably, these are polysemes rather than homonyms. Another example of a switch to a different but obviously still related meaning is the definition of transitive 'vote': 'to get {people} [out] to vote'. _They voted the suburbs._

Answer (score 4):

The phenomenon and label of the change is one thing, and the result is labeled another thing.

In the specific community (of aviation; I don't think I've heard this at all before so I'm assuming it is limited to here), it is simply a change in syntax accompanied by semantic drift.

The result, where a passive form is interpreted actively, is called a

> [deponent verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponent_verb)

In any other circumstance I would call this an error, but if everybody in the community consistently uses it that way, then that's 'correct'/how you do it/how you'd be understood for that community.

If I were forced at gunpoint to encapsulate everything into one word, I would say that 'violate' was

> deponentized

but that's a bit of a mouthful so I'd prefer

> "**'violate' became a deponent verb**".

There are other words to describe the nuances of process/different usage though. The 'agency' of the subject is changed despite the usual conventions of active or passive form. Likewise the valency (number of nouns related by the verb) changed. It's as though the active bivalent/transitive 'The pilot violated the rule' changed to the active univalent/intransitive 'the pilot violated (committed a violation)', and the intransitive slipped into the similarly univalent form of the passive 'the pilot was violated' idiomatically (but keeping the order and semantics of the active).

Comment: I think one potential rationale is a *violation* is a count noun, and for pilots the count is *very important*. Like points on your driving license, accruing too many violations, even minor ones, can lead to revocation. And, as my English teacher in 10th grade used to point out "When a paper is handed back with an A, you tell everyone '**I got** an A!', but when it comes back with an F, you cry '**He gave** me an F!". Similarly, if pilots feel they've been cited for a violation unjustly, they can say the administration *violated* them. Pure speculation, but plausible and fun.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked for other examples.

Here's one example:

Police officer 1: "Should we trespass him"?

Police officer 2: "Yes, let's trespass him".

Police officer 1 (to subject being detained):

"You are trespassed from here, do you understand?"  -- meaning you will be charged with trespassing if you ever come back to the location

Many examples of this can be found on websites featuring bodycam videos from law enforcement.

See for example 12:48-13:02 here:

[Freedom Christopher Phaendler's Walmart Arrest](https://youtu.be/nyW5S2nvEIo?t=768) on YouTube.

And here's another example that is *somewhat* parallel:

> When the landlord "takes steps to forfeit a lease" it means that the
> landlord is causing the lease to be canceled, to be placed in
> forfeiture. It is the tenant who forfeits right in such a case, but
> the landlord who takes action. to say "the landlord forfeits the
> lease" is short for "the landlord places the lease into forfeiture".
> Yes this usage can be confusing, but it is quite common.

From [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/89400) in the "Law" Stack Exchange site.

Granted, to be *completely* parallel to the case in the original question, it might have to be the *tenant* that was "forfeited" by the landlord, not the lease.